# Al hacer push en mi repositorio local me dice que el permiso esta denegado

Tags: git, github, git-push, error-403

Tengo un repositorio local en mi pc, e intento hacer push desde git al remoto en GitHub. Sin embargo me aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo configuro el nombre de usuario y correo tanto global como a nivel de repositorio, el mismo que tengo con la cuenta de GitHub en la que quiero hacer push. Sin embargo me sigue apareciendo lo mismo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

antes tenia git con dicha cuenta: maria-arcila82221 y maria_arcila82221@elpoli.edu.co; sin embargo por cuestiones la cambie a la que les muestro.
Pero a pesar de todo ello sigue apareciendo como si estuviese con la anterior(maria-arcila82221) la cual claramente no tiene permiso para el repositorio de la que actualmente quiero usar(mariajosearcano).

Intente eliminar tambien dicha cuenta con estos comandos

```
git config --global --unset user.name "maria-arcila82221"
git config --global --unset user.email "maria_arcila82221@elpoli.edu.co"
```

sin embargo sigue apareciendo exactamente lo mismo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor pueden ayudarme que estado probando muchas cosas y nada que se soluciona, ademas desde Visual Studio Code con la integracion de git hago lo mismo y me pide hacer fork(supongo que es por lo mismo).

PD: revise el archivo .gitconfig y tengo el usuario correspondiente para el push al repo remoto(mariajosearcano)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que no has iniciado sesión en Git. Simplemente ingresar su usuario o correo en la línea de comandos no funcionará para las versiones más recientes de git.

Para usar Git en la línea de comandos, deberás descargar, instalar y configurar Git en tu equipo. También puede instalar GitHub CLI para usar GitHub desde la línea de comandos.

Usa este comando para instalar desde winget la CLI de GitHub:

```
winget install --id GitHub.cli
```

Para obtener más información sobre otros sistemas operativos, visite [github.com/cli/cli](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation).

Después de la instalación, es posible que necesites reiniciar el editor de código si estás utilizando su terminal.

Cuando te conectes a un repositorio de GitHub desde Git, deberás autenticarte con GitHub mediante HTTPS o SSH. Puedes autenticarse en GitHub mediante la GitHub CLI, ya sea para HTTP o SSH. Utiliza el siguiente comando:

```
gh auth login
```

Proporciona la información necesaria y habrás iniciado sesión.

[cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)

Comment: Me sirvio muchisimas gracias!